# Extract month from date

Tags: postgresql

I would like to extract the month of a given date in postgres e.g. '2020-02-03' --> 2.
I tried this with `substr('2020-03-01',6,2)` it´s working, but I am getting the zero also.
`date_part('month','2020-01-01')` as well as `extract(month from date '2020-01-01')` [edit: syntax error]
is leading to an error.

How can I do it in the best way?

Comment: what do you get by `select extract(month from date '2020-02-01')`? can you also share the error message?

Comment: Don’t say “leading to an error”, without mentioning what that error actually _is_.

Comment: And what is the data type of your *date* ?

Comment: `extract(month from date '2020-01-01') ` is working [just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5e8db87efd692f07cf0052aee5f48973) - what exactly is the error you get?

Comment: SELECT extract(month from date '2020-01-01'); works fine, what's the (classified?) error that you see?

Comment: Sorry; I tried `extract()` again and now it´s working, somewhere had to be a "real" syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not attempt to parse dates as strings. `EXTRACT(MONTH` is exactly what you're looking for:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM '2020-02-03'::DATE);
 date_part 
-----------
         2
```

If your date is formatted as `YYYYDDMM` try:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('2020-03-02','YYYY-DD-MM'));
 date_part 
-----------
         2
```